# How do I use the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit?

Tags: javascript, html, toolkit

I am working on a web visualization project and would like to use the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit to create interactive graphs quickly in webpages. However, I have no idea how to start using it or even where to look for clues. The google group seems like it is mostly high level stuff, but I applied for membership and am waiting on a response.

What do I need to know in order to start using this toolkit, or more generally, any toolkit?

Website;
http://thejit.org/

Answer (score 0):

Download the source code and look in the examples page, my advise is too open the results with FireBug and look at the example javascript code ;)

It's very easy to setup, you just need to change the "data" JSON and you'r all set ;)